# Whats best practice when storing GraphQL queries using Apollo client in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have several different GraphQL queries. For example

```
const FETCH_PERSON = gql`"some query"`
```

That i just store as a const in the compnent file im using it in for now.

My question is what is the best practice when it comes to storing hardcoded queries? And maybe some queries that requires 1 or more parameters.

Is it creating a helper class with all the functions that return the full query string? Or what other alternative is there?

And how should that helper method/function look like? Would appreciate an example of input and output and how to use it with Apollo.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just create a file in your client app that defines and exports all your pre-defined queries, e.g.:

```
export const FETCH_PERSON = gql`some query`
export const FETCH_OTHER = gql`some other query`
```

And them import them wherever needed. You'll typically define variables where they are used since those will come from the components.

2. You can also use [automatic persisted queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/apq/) on the server.